# Help with translating Hamiltonian into matrix

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematical-modeling, quantum-mechanics, model-hamiltonians, programming

Eq. 19 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.3536.pdf) gives the following Hamiltonian:

[image]

$\sigma_a, \tau_a, \eta_a$ are respectively the spin, sublattice pseudospin and valley pseudospin respectively.

Normally, I would have chosen a basis convention such as $\sigma_a, \tau_a, \eta_a$ and plugged in the $2\times 2$ identity matrix for terms that don't appear above. Then I would have taken the Kronecker Delta product. However, in this case, the authors explicitly define $(s_z,\tau_z\,\eta_z)=(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$ for $($up/down, sublattice A/B, valley K/K'$)$ respectively. So, as a relatively inexperienced person in the field, I feel like there is some ambiguity. I am having trouble translating the above into a matrix that I can play with numerically.
Can someone help me understand the convention here?

I tried two interpretations in Python. `np.kron` takes the Kronecker product. First attempt:

```
# Choose basis: (tau_xy, sigma_xyz), replace sz, tauz, etaz by s, tau, eta = +/- 1
# Gives 4-band model, with eye = identity and s_xyz as Pauli matrices
eta = 1; # instead of using eta_z as the Pauli z matrix
h1=h*vf*(eta*kx*np.kron(sx,eye)+ky*np.kron(sy,eye)) # e-e hoppings
h2=lSO*eta*np.kron(eye,sz)*tau # SO coupling
h3=m*np.kron(eye,sz)*tau # break TRS (AFM exchange mag.)
H = h1+h2+h3
```

Second:

```
# Choose basis: (eta, sigma, tau) using Pauli matrices for all, but no +/- 1 values.
# Gives 8-band model.
h1=h*vf*(kx*np.kron(sz,np.kron(eye,sx))+ky*np.kron(eye,np.kron(eye,sy))) # e-e hoppings
h2=lSO*np.kron(sz,np.kron(sz,sz)) # SO coupling
h3=m*np.kron(eye,np.kron(sz,sz))# break TRS (AFM exchange mag.)
H = h1+h2+h3
```

Both of these seem to give me very weird Berry curvature fields when plotted. So, I figured I am doing something wrong. Note: I set $v_F = 1, \hbar=1$.

Answer (score 8):

[For this type of calculation, I find MATLAB/Octave to be easier](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2672/2293), at least for demonstrating what to do. You can add the `np.` everywhere afterwards if you want to use Python.

Assuming you have the following matrices already defined in your workspace:

$\eta_z$ = `eta`
$\tau_x$ = `taux`
$\tau_y$ = `tauy`
$\tau_z$ = `tauz`
$m_z$ = `tauz`
$\sigma_z$ = `sigmaz`,

and the following scalars:

$\hbar$ = `hbar`
$v_F$ = `v`
$\lambda_{\textrm{SO}}$ = `lambda`,
$k_x$ = `kx`
$k_y$ = `ky`,

the matrix would typically be calculated in the following manner:

```
eta=kron(kron(kron(eta,eye(length(mz)),eye(length(sigmaz)),eye(length(tauz)); 
mz=kron(kron(eye(length(eta)),mz),eye(length(mz)+length(sigmaz)+length(tauz)))));    
sigmaz=kron(kron(eye(length(eta)+length(mz)),sigmaz),eye(length(tauz)));    
tauz=(kron(eye(length(eta)+length(mz)+length(sigmaz)),tauz)));
taux=(kron(eye(length(eta)+length(mz)+length(sigmaz)),taux)));
tauy=(kron(eye(length(eta)+length(mz)+length(sigmaz)),tauy)));

h1 = hbar*v*(eta*kx*taux + ky*tauy);
h2 = lambda*eta*sigmaz*tauz;
h3 = mz*sigmaz*tauz;
H = h1+h2+h3;
```

The is because typically:

$\tau_x,\tau_z,$ and $\tau_y$ would all lie in the same Hilbert space, and
 
$\eta_z,m_z$ and $\sigma_z$ would each lie in a different Hilbert spaces to everything else.

There's a lot of left and right parentheses which you'd have to be careful about matching, and since there's 6 operators involved across 4 different Hilbert spaces, this is not such a simple example. If you wanted to give a simpler example with fewer operators and types of operators, or to explicitly give each matrix, I could try to simplify my above code. The `length(operator)` functions can probably all be replaced by `2`, but my code works more generally for arbitrary spin (not just spin-1/2 which has eigenvalues $\pm$1, but also spin-1 which has eigenvalues -1,0,1, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the underlying problem better! I had a few clarifications to request: 1) I chose all matrices `eta` through `sigmaz` to be their `2 x 2` Pauli matrix equivalents. Is this okay? 2) Following that, I added parentheses to some lines to match them up (next comment), but it seems as if `eta` is of dimensions `16 x 16` whereas the others are different. This seems to cause problems in defining `H`. 3) The authors use $\pm 1$ for $s_z,\tau_z\,\eta_z$, but now I am not sure how to test specific cases (such as $s_z,\tau_z\,\eta_z=1,-1,1$). Any advice?

Comment: Example code: `eta=np.kron(np.kron(np.kron(eta,np.eye(2)),np.eye(2)),np.eye(2)); ` and `mz=np.kron(np.kron(np.eye(2),mz),np.eye(6));` respectively have dimensions `16 x 16` and `24 x 24`, whereas others have `12 x 12`. Clearly I've fumbled somewhere, because this mismatch is keeping `H` from being well-defined.

Comment: I believe `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` should all be `16x16`. I'm not at my computer until much later, but I'll look at what might have happened, as soon as I get a chance (today's a very busy day for me).

Comment: thanks, I’ll keep trying! :D